# MDBIcon not displaying icons in React App

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design, mdbreact

I am trying to use MDB React forms in my application.
I have downloaded mdbreact using the command npm install --save mdbreact.

Below is the code snippet :

```
       <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
          <MDBBtn className="btn btn-outline-purple" type="submit">
            Send
            <MDBIcon far icon="paper-plane" className="ml-2" />
          </MDBBtn>
        </div>
```

but the icon is not displayed and MDBBtn color is not purple.
Anyone, please suggest.

Comment: I don't see a snippet.

Comment: @stever Code Snipppet is attached now

Comment: far icon looks wrong.  try `farIcon`

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Try it without the word `far`.  Also, are you importing like this `import { MDBIcon, MDBBtn } from "mdbreact"` ?

Comment: I have added "import "mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css";,now the colour is displaying purple,but still the icon is missing.Yes ,I have imported all these such as { MDBIcon, MDBBtn }

Comment: Did you remove the word "far"?

Comment: Yes,still the same

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you have to add in index.js
these importations:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css";
```

check the documentation about mdbreact...you find this..

Answer (score 0):

1. `npm install mdbreact`
2. `import { MDBIcon} from 'mdbreact';`
3. 

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'mdbreact/dist/css/mdb.css';
```

4. use it: `<MDBIcon icon="lightbulb" size="4x"/>`

Comment: would you add a brief explanation of why those steps fix the issue in the question?